# CryptoCurrency - Communication between full nodes in Byteball

Tags: node.js, websocket, directed-acyclic-graphs, cryptocurrency

In Byteball, Every device connects to its home hub using websockets, that is, communication between every devices and between light client and full nodes is done by [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Then how can communication between full nodes implemented?

For storing all status of byteball in full nodes database, connection between full nodes should be existed.

What is the way to communicate between full nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The communication between two wallets is done via the hub. The sender wallet sends the message to the recipient's hub and the hub forwards it to the recipient. If the recipient is not online, the hub stores the messages and forwards them when the wallet reconnects again. Note that the communication is encrypted end-to-end between the sender and recipient, the hub cannot decrypt messages passed between wallets.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I want to know how to communicate between full nodes, not wallets.

Comment: Full nodes are usually wallets, if not, they can be hubs or relays. I think you are asking about relays. They all use the same websocket connection for communication eg. when passing new units to known peers.

Comment: Check out "Accepting incoming connections" https://github.com/byteball/byteballcore/blob/master/README.md

Comment: A full wallet acts as a relay if it exposes the web service port publicly. If it also sets the bServeAsHub option to true, it will act as a hub in addition.